# Dúvida em como selecionar um registro via linq

Tags: c#, web-service, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma tabela, onde eu gravo apenas *scripts*. Há um campo, onde eu separo se é script técnico ou script central. Há um campo `TipoScript` que char e é "C" ou "T". Essa tabela não foi bem feita, sem pensar no futuro, de forma que temos o campo `NomeScript`, que sempre tem o mesmo nome para *script* `Técnico` e o mesmo nome para script Central.

A minha consulta deverá retornar os dois *scripts*, mas terei que fazer a diferenciação entre ambos. Confesso não saber fazer isso. Poderia colocar assim: `tecnico = sc.scripttecnico`, mas a única forma de saber é pelo campo `TipoScript` e nomear campo como eu fiz acima, tem dado pau.

Alguém poderia me sugerir como fazer isso? Pode ser em *lambda* também.

Esse é meu LINQ:

```
public TPDV getCnpjParceiro(string cnpj)
        {
            WEBEntities db = new WEBEntities();
            TPDV pdv = new TPDV();
            List<string> lista = new List<string>();

            var resultado = (from _lista in db.T_PDV
                             where _lista.CNPJ == cnpj
                             join _st in db.T_CRM_StatusPDV on _lista.CNPJ equals(_st.DE_Cnpj)
                             join _sc in db.T_Script on _st.IT_Status equals((int)_sc.TipoStatus)
                             select new
                             {
                                 _lista.CNPJ,
                                 _lista.RazaoSocial,
                                 _lista.Endereco,
                                 _lista.CaminhoLogo,
                                 _lista.Bairro,
                                 _lista.Cidade,
                                 _st.IT_Status,
                                 _st.DT_TransacaoV,
                                 _sc.Script
                             }).ToList();

            foreach (var lis in resultado)
            {
                pdv.CNPJ = lis.CNPJ;
                pdv.RazaoSocial = lis.RazaoSocial;
                pdv.Endereco = lis.Endereco;
                pdv.CaminhoLogo = lis.CaminhoLogo;
                pdv.Bairro = lis.Bairro;
                pdv.Cidade = lis.Cidade;
            }

            return pdv;

        }
```

Tentei fazer assim, mas dá erro em tecnico e central

```
var resultado = (from _lista in db.T_PDV
                             where _lista.CNPJ == cnpj
                             join _st in db.T_CRM_StatusPDV on _lista.CNPJ equals(_st.DE_Cnpj)
                             join _sc in db.T_Script on _st.IT_Status equals((int)_sc.TipoStatus)
                             select new
                             {
                                 _lista.CNPJ,
                                 _lista.RazaoSocial,
                                 _lista.Endereco,
                                 _lista.CaminhoLogo,
                                 _lista.Bairro,
                                 _lista.Cidade,
                                 _st.IT_Status,
                                 _st.DT_TransacaoV,
                                 tecnico = _sc.TipoScript == "T" ? _sc.Script : null,
                                 central = _sc.TipoScript == "C" ? _sc.Script : null
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Está dando algum erro ?

Answer (score 3):

Use models e retorne-os na sua consulta LINQ.

#### Model

```
public class Script
{
    public string TipoScript { get; set; }
    public string Script { get; set; }
}
```

#### Consulta LINQ

```
var resultado = from s in db.Script select s;
```

`resultado` será um `IQueryable<Script>`. A partir daí é só usar na usa View e fazer o teste do tipo

```
@model IQueryable<Path.Completo.Da.Classe.Script>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    if (item.TipoScript == "C")
    {
        // Lógica para Central
    } else
    {
        // Lógica para técnico
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu tenho dúvida quanto a isso. Em verdade isso será exportado via web service através de um objeto, que no meu caso é do tipo PDV. Essa é a dúvida. Vou editar meu post e mostrar o meu linq

Comment: Eu postei essa versão porque você usou a tag `asp.net-mvc-5`

Comment: É verdade, nem percebi isso, sério. Vou retirar, nem sei se consigo

Answer (score 0):

A forma com resolvi foi. Fiz em separado os scripts pata Técnico e Central e depois adicionei ao objeto.